# line breaks in javascript generated csv for excel import

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I generate and download a CSV from a webpage using javascript in the browser side (chrome windows)

```
function toCsv(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(csvString, row){
        csvString += row.join(',') ;
    csvString += "\r\n";  //";";//"\n";
        return csvString;
    }, '');
}

function flowDataCsv(){
    document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' + toCsv(flowDataGrid);
}
```

i have tried delimiting lines with ";", "\r\n" and "\n" but all three results in csv:s that excel imports into one line instead of as a grid. How should i terminate the lines to get excel to recognize it as a line ending and start inserting data on a new line?

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if you still need the answer to this question.  But will post the solution I found as I experienced the same problem.

Using your code above the only thing you are missing is to encode your csv string returned by your toCsv function.  This would look like this in your code above:

```
function toCsv(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(csvString, row){
        csvString += row.join(',') ;
    csvString += "\r\n";  //";";//"\n";
        return encodeURIComponent(csvString);
    }, '');
}

function flowDataCsv(){
    document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' + toCsv(flowDataGrid);
}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who comes across this issue again in the future!

Comment: not converting \n to new line and distorts float values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to solve this issue but had no luck, but encodeURIComponent really worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try `\u2028` instead of `\n` or  `\u2029` in place of `\r`.

src: https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv/issues/91#issuecomment-276555551

Comment: could you explain why